# Django CustomUser password visible when creating superuser

Tags: django, django-custom-user

I extended default `User` model as follow:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False)
    is_teacher  models.BooleanField(default = False)
    ...
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username','password', 'is_teacher']
```

Now when creating a new superuser the prompt for password is not hidden

```
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
Email address: user1@coolapp.com
First name: John
Last name: Smith
Username: cool_username
Is teacher: True
Password: fancy_p4$$w0rd
Superuser created successfully.
```

Is there any way it can be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

When defining `REQUIRED_FIELDS` in the `CustomUser` model, just skip `password`. The default password prompt will show up after the list is iterated completely:

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'is_teacher']
```

Now when creating a new superuser:

```
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
Email address: user1@coolapp.com
First name: John
Last name: Smith
Username: cool_username
Is teacher: True
Password: 
Password (again): 
Superuser created successfully.
```